# arquillian-was-embedded-8 runs but can't inject EJB. NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, jboss-arquillian

I tried to inject my EJB bean in Arquillian integration tests with WebSphere embedded container. When injecting EJB I get the NullPointerException. But container is started correctly, because translogs are occured. I followed the exmaple at the https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-was/blob/master/was-embedded-8/src/test/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/was/embedded_8/WebSphereEmbeddedIntegrationClientTestCase.java

My test code:

```
package com.daoleen.websphere.arquillian.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;

import javax.ejb.EJB;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.daoleen.websphere.arquillian.beans.MyBean;
import com.daoleen.websphere.arquillian.beans.repository.MyBeanRepository;


@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SimpleArquillianTest {

    @EJB(lookup="ejblocal:ejb/session/MyBeanRepository")
    private MyBeanRepository myBean;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "ArqTest.jar")
                .addPackage(SimpleArquillianTest.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(MyBean.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(MyBeanRepository.class.getPackage())
                .addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml")
                .addAsResource("logging.properties")
                .addAsResource("META-INF/ejb-jar.xml")
                .addAsResource("META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml");

        System.out.println("Archive contains: " + archive.toString(true));
        return archive;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccess() {
        assertEquals("success", "success");
    }

    @Test
    public void failTest() {
        assertNull(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBean() {
        assertEquals("hello", myBean.hello());
    }
}
```

MyBean.java

```
package com.daoleen.websphere.arquillian.beans;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import com.daoleen.websphere.arquillian.beans.repository.MyBeanRepository;

@Stateless
@Local(MyBeanRepository.class)
public class MyBean implements MyBeanRepository {
    @Override
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello bean");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

MyBeanRepository.java

```
package com.daoleen.websphere.arquillian.beans.repository;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface MyBeanRepository {
    public String hello();
}
```

ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" 
    version="1.0">

 <session name="MyBean">
    <interface class="com.daoleen.websphere.arquillian.beans.repository.MyBeanRepository" binding-name="ejblocal:ejb/session/MyBeanRepository"/>          
 </session>  
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

If I deploy the output _DEFAULT___DEFAULT__ArqTest.jar file into WebSphere App Server, the binding for my bean works correct:
[image: in app server works correct]

Does anyone know how to inject EJB in the arquillian test?
Thanks in advance

UPD: I found when EJB does not implements any interfaces than injection works. But if EJB implements any interface (with or without @Local) injection doesn't works. I can't understand why.
Example:
The bean written as

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello bean");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Works fine, but

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyBeanRepository {
    @Override
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello bean");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

doesn't work

Comment: Can you try @Inject?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But @Inject also got me the NullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry that this comment doesn't address your question, but how where you able to find the maven dependency for arquillian-was-embedded-8? Version 1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT is not being resolved and more people are having the same issue (see [1]). It would be great if you could give a hint. Thanks!

[1] http://arquillian.org/blog/2015/01/29/arquillian-container-was-1-0-0-Beta2/

Comment: Hi, narko! You need to compile this artifact from source code. The source code you can download from github: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-was

Comment: As I remember, you need to specify the path to your local WebSphere AS installation for your local machine in the pom.xml file.