# Arquillian can't load LoadableExtension for Websphere Embedded Container

Tags: ejb, websphere, jboss-arquillian

I can't make **Arquillian** and **Websphere Embedded EJBContainer** work smoothly together. 
Because I can't use the arquillian-was-embedded-8 Jar File (Missing in Company Maven repository and Jenkins).

I try to load the WebSphereExtension (**LoadableExtension**) in my Junit test without success. Can someone point me to the right solution?

My second question is, even if i load this jar file locally in my IDE i also have problems with the **interface** (on my EJB's). See the same issue here:
[[arquillian-was-embedded-8 runs but can't inject EJB. NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013911/arquillian-was-embedded-8-runs-but-cant-inject-ejb-nullpointerexception][1])
How can i avoid this?

My maven Dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
           <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
           <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.ejb.embeddableContainer</artifactId>
           <version>8.0.0.11</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
<dependency>
           <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
           <artifactId>endorsed_apis</artifactId>
           <version>8.0.0.11</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>       
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-build</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>       
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.Final</version>           
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>                 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.Final</version>          
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Java 6, Junit 4.12, IDE Luna 4.4.2

Thank you in advance, I would appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I don't need to build the artifacts if I use this
in src/test/resources/META-INF/services/**org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.LoadableExtension** (this is a file name)
with the contents --> /path/to/WebSphereExtension

The second problem I resolve like this:

@EJB(mappedName = "java:global/test/MyEjbTest!**com.home.coem.Processor**")

Processor test1;

**Processor** is the interface name and **MyEjbTest** is the implementation bean!

I hope it will help somebody

Comment: WebSphere Application Server never uses `mappedName`.  If it has an effect, I am somehow doubting that you are actually using the WebSphere embeddable container.

Comment: Hi Brett, In the LoadableExtension class you have a register method  that you can override Here you can make the call to WebSphereEmbeddedContainer.